# Drools: how to get the facts and globals in the knowledge base after a REST call to fireAllRules?

Tags: java, windows, websphere, drools, redhat

I'm working on a project with Red Hat Drools deployed on a WAS 8.5.9 on windows and I'm trying to figure out how to get the facts and the globals in the knowledge base after I fire the rules in my session with a REST call.

The REST API I'm using is:

[POST] http://localhost:9080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/instances/TargaRuleContainer

Where "TargaRuleContainer" is the id of my container. Here is the code of my application:

kmodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="targa" packages="com.sample">
        <ksession name="targaSession" type="stateless">
        </ksession>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

Rule file:

```
package com.sample

import com.sample.targaRule.model.Targa;
import static com.sample.targaRule.util.Utils.targaPari;

global java.lang.String city


rule "Targa default"
    salience -10
    activation-group "targaActivation"
    ruleflow-group "targa"
    when
    then
        city = "No city";
        System.out.println("No City!");
end

rule "Targa OK Milano"
    salience 10
    activation-group "targaActivation"
    ruleflow-group "targa"
    when
        t : Targa( targaPari(targa) )
    then
        t.setCity("Milano");
        city = "Milano";
        System.out.println("Milano!!");
        update(t)
end

rule "Targa NO Milano"
    salience 10
    activation-group "targaActivation"
    ruleflow-group "targa"
    when
        t : Targa( !targaPari(targa) )
    then
        t.setCity("Roma");
        city = "Roma";
        System.out.println("Roma!!");
        update(t)
end
```

POJO class:

```
package com.sample.targaRule.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Targa implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String nome, cognome, targa, city;

    public Targa() {
        super();
    }

    public Targa(String nome, String cognome, String targa) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.targa = targa;
        this.city = "";
    }

    public Targa(String nome, String cognome, String targa, String city) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.targa = targa;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }

    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public String getTarga() {
        return targa;
    }

    public void setTarga(String targa) {
        this.targa = targa;
    }

}
```

Utils class:

```
package com.sample.targaRule.util;

public class Utils {
    public static boolean targaPari(String t) {
        int lastNum = Integer.parseInt(t.substring(4,5));
        if (lastNum%2==0) {
            System.out.println("Checking plate "+t+": last number is "+lastNum+", so even");
            return true;
        }

        System.out.println("Checking plate "+t+": last number is "+lastNum+", so odd");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the body of my request:

```
{
    "lookup": "targaSession",
    "commands": [{
            "insert": {
                "object": {
                    "com.sample.targaRule.model.Targa": {
                        "nome": "Donald",
                        "cognome": "Trump",
                        "targa": "ED222ED",
                        "city": ""
                        }
                },
                "out-identifier": "Input"
            }
        }, {
            "fire-all-rules": {
                "out-identifier": "FireAllRules"
            }
        }, {
            "get-objects": {
                "out-identifier": "Output"
            }
        },  {
            "get-global": {
                "out-identifier": "Global",
                "identifier": "city"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the response from the server:

```
{
  "type" : "SUCCESS",
  "msg" : "Container TargaRuleContainer successfully called.",
  "result" : {
    "execution-results" : {
      "results" : [ {
        "key" : "Input",
        "value" : {"com.sample.targaRule.model.Targa":{
  "nome" : "Donald",
  "cognome" : "Trump",
  "targa" : "ED222ED",
  "city" : ""
}}
      }, {
        "key" : "Output",
        "value" : [{"com.sample.targaRule.model.Targa":{
  "nome" : "Donald",
  "cognome" : "Trump",
  "targa" : "ED222ED",
  "city" : ""
}}]
      }, {
        "key" : "FireAllRules",
        "value" : 0
      }, {
        "key" : "Global"
      } ],
      "facts" : [ {
        "key" : "Input",
        "value" : {"org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle":{
  "external-form" : "0:1:-1324533475:-1324533475:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.sample.targaRule.model.Targa"
}}
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

The rule just does a check on the "targa" string field of the pojo class (checks if the third-to-last char is an odd or even number), and sets the other string field "city" accordingly. It also sets a string global variable named "city", and does a System.out.println().

As you can see in the response, the call is successful, but I cannot see the edits in the object I insert, neither I can see the global variable.

Moreover, the `System.out.println()` that is in the first 2 rules consequences is not shown in the server logs, I can just see the print that is done in the Utls class static method I call in the rules conditions.

I'm quite sure I am doing something wrong in the request syntax, but I'm having a hard time finding some example online, as the Red Hat documentation is not that verbose.

EDIT1: I figured out the problem with the output of the POJO field "city". The problem was the "ruleflow-group" parameter set in the rules body (I need that cause I'm using the same rules within a jbpm process too). I solved by inserting the "auto-focus" parameter in the rules.

For what concerns the global variable, doing some reverse engineering I found out that (probably) globals are admitted only in stateful sessions, so I changed my kmodule.xml accordingly, but still I cannot get the global variable "city" in output.